# General-purpose non-interactive multi-party computation protocol

Tags: protocol-design, secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

Most of general purpose multi-party computation protocols are highly interactive.
Especially the ones with Shamir's secret scheme, as there is a degree reduction step in multiplication that needs the parties to interact with each other.

For example, say a client (trusted dealer) distributes the secret among several servers via secure channels, and the client also provides inputs to all the servers needed for secure function evaluation. Now the servers should evaluate a function on their own, they cannot talk to each other. At the end, the client receives all the partial results from different servers (via secure channels) and constructs the complete result locally.

There are non-interactive and robust threshold decryption protocols of RSA which are specialized multi party protocols. But are there any general-purpose non-interactive multi-party computation protocols? Or is it an open problem ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "non-interactive"? Obviously there will have to be some interaction.

Comment: non-interactive means, the parties don't interact with each other. only the dealer gets all the partial results and collates them . if we use Shamir's scheme , the parties would need to interact for degree reduction while multiplication, for addition they need not ofcourse .

Comment: Who is the dealer in an MPC protocol?

Comment: the dealer is who distributed the shares to each server , say a client distributes the shares among servers , once the protocol of function evaluation is over, all the partial results are collated by client . in a non-interactive protocol servers should not talk to each other

Comment: "the dealer is who distributed" _what_ shares to each server? $\:$ You allude to secret sharing in your first paragraph and your tags and your comments, but neither of your questions mention it. $\:$ Is it the case that the dealer is still trusted after having dealt and that the parties have a confidential channel to that dealer?

Comment: edited the question accordingly for more clarity .

Comment: Does the client receive the partial results via secure channels? $\;$

Comment: yes clients get the partial results via secure channels

Comment: You should change your question. Whatever it is you are asking about, it's not multi-party computation. In a multi-party computation protocol, multiple parties compute a function on secret inputs from each party. There is no dealer and usually no partial results.

Comment: give me reference. without a dealer how is the secret shared ? ideally , each party gets results from others and collates itself if it requests the function evaluation

Comment: http://www.pinkas.net/PAPERS/ANP04.pdf . $\:$ The secret$s$ (which in that case are "state-information string"s) $\hspace{.49 in}$ are shared by the protocol. $\;\;\;$

Comment: Interesting but this is one the case. but not generalized SMC,  you would find secret sharing scheme to be heart of SMC in most protocols , refer martin giesler's mpc thesis .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by interaction.

Some protocols for secure multiparty computation, e.g. those based on Shamir secret sharings and the GMW protocol, require the servers to communicate a lot during the computation.

In other protocols, such as those based on Yao's garbled circuits (e.g. [Fairplay MP](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1455770.1455804)), the interaction between servers is reduced in that the servers only need to communicate during a *constant* number of rounds, that is, a number of rounds that is independent of the size of the function they compute. But still, a lot of data traffic between the servers are needed during these rounds.

Some work has been done to further reduce the interaction required by secure multiparty computation. See for example this paper: [Secure Computation on the Web: Computing without Simultaneous Interaction](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/157). This is in some sense non-interactive secure multiparty computation, but unfortunately the paper shows that it only works for a limited class of functions.